# Take users with SQL Server database backup and restore them at another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to take users with a SQL Server database backup and restore them at another server?

Comment: Please, refer to this [article](https://www.petri.com/backup-restore-users-remote-sql-database-tsql-PowerShell)

Comment: you can also refer to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992

Comment: The database backup is a **database-level** operation - and it **will** take along all the **users** defined in that database. But those users most likely will refer to **Logins** at the **server-level**, and those cannot be included in a **database** backup ....

Answer (score 0):

After restoring the database, you can list the users and the corresponding security identifiers (SID) in the restored (current) database that are not linked to any login in the new server.

run the following script:

```
 EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

You can fix the login by executing the following script for every login reported in the above script:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'AUTO_FIX', '<reported user name>', NULL, '<password>'
```